# atd stuck jobs in queue

Tags: 18.04

I am on Bionic (18.04.4) and I see that my jobs are stuck in the queue and
never run!

```
[root@myhost2: log]# atq
3267   Tue Jun 16 03:34:00 2020 = root
697    Mon Jun 15 19:36:00 2020 = root
3268   Tue Jun 16 03:34:00 2020 = root
3265   Tue Jun 16 03:31:00 2020 = root
7566   Tue Jun 16 22:17:00 2020 a root
7563   Tue Jun 16 22:16:00 2020 a root
697    Mon Jun 15 19:36:00 2020 a root

[root@myhost2: log]# service atd status 
* atd.service - Deferred execution scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/atd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-06-16 14:03:35 PDT; 8h ago
     Docs: man:atd(8)
Main PID: 731 (atd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/atd.service
       `-731 /usr/sbin/atd -f

Jun 16 22:20:21 myhost2 atd[19018]: File a002b90194efbc is in wrong format - aborting
Jun 16 22:20:21 myhost2 atd[19019]: File a002b90194efbc is in wrong format - aborting
Jun 16 22:20:21 myhost2 atd[19020]: File a002b90194efbc is in wrong format - aborting
Jun 16 22:20:21 myhost2 atd[19021]: File a002b90194efbc is in wrong format - aborting
```

The file being pointed to (`a002b90194efbc`) is *empty*!

If I delete the files in spool and reboot it becomes ok, but not sure when it
might go back to the same bad state!

How do I make sure to never get into this stuck state!? Or, if stuck, any way to
auto recover?

--
Thanks

Comment: You don't say what printer is involved and how it is accessed but does this reference provide any clues? https://www.unix.com/sco/37143-print-jobs-getting-stuck-queue.html

Comment: There are no print jobs, these are my regular unix commands which I run via `at` for deferred execution (like for e.g. `reboot | at now+5mins`). When I said spool, I meant `/var/spool/cron/atjobs` - the directory where the jobs file are kept